# how to migration from CommonsChunkPlugin to splitChunks after upgrade to webpack 5

Tags: webpack

I am developing a google chrome extension, when I am using lower version of webpack, I configure the chunk like this way:

```
    plugins : [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin( {
      name : 'commons1',
      filename : 'commons1.js' , 
      allChunks: true,
      chunks : [ 'popup','content' ],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual',
    }) ,
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ 
      name: 'commons2',
      filename :'commons2.js' , 
      allChunks: true,
      chunks : [ 'commons1.js' , 'options' ] 
    }) ,
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ 
      name: 'commons3',
      filename :'commons3.js' , 
      allChunks: true,
      chunks : [ 'bg' , 'commons2.js' ] 
    }) ,
    new ExtractTextPlugin( '[name].css' )
  ]
```

after upgade to webpack 5, they removed the `CommonsChunkPlugin` and use `splitChunks`, I read the splitChunks docs and did not figure out how to migrate my old configuration to the new `splitChunks`. Is it possible to migration the old configuration to the new `splitChunks`? what is the equal way to write conifguration using `splitChunks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In splitChunk I write it like this way:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons1: {
          name: 'commons1',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(popup|content)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
        commons2: {
          name: 'commons2',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(options|commons1)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
        commons3: {
          name: 'commons3',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(bg|commons2)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
      }
    }
  },
```